# Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used) in ubuntu16.04 in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, computer-vision, intel, openvino

I am using a Docker container in which I installed Ubuntu 16.04.  I tried to setup IOT based people_counter Project so i install OpenVINO Toolkit, and after installing i run the command and at last I got the following error when I Build and start the main application that does people counting using deep learning inference.

I run the program:

```
./obj_recognition \
      -i Pedestrain_Detect_2_1_1.mp4 \
      -m /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/intel_models/person-detection-retail-0012/FP16/person-detection-retail-0012.xml \
      -l /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/intel_models/person-detection-retail-0012/FP16/person-detection-retail-0012.bin \
      -d GPU \
      -t SSD \
      -thresh 0.7 0 \
      2>/dev/null \
  | ffmpeg \
      -v warning
      -f rawvideo
      -pixel_format bgr24
      -video_size 544x320
      -i -
      http://localhost:8090/fac.ffm
```

and I got this:

```
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

What can I do?

Edit:
After  [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) sugestion

removing -v warning i run the command and i got this  :

```
 libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
 libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
 libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
 libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
 libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
 libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
   libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 104448 kb/s
   Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 544x320,   104448 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
 Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/fac.ffm':
 Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-09-05 06:55:30
  encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
   Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuv420p, 852x480, q=2-31, 8192 kb/s, 25 fps,  1000k tbn, 25 tbc
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg
 Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))
 frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       4kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
  video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
  Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with `[intel]`, computer vision, or Python, it's just a bash scripting error.  Please retag with `[bash]` if that's the shell you're using.

Comment: An issue I ran into with this message was that I was setting the seek position (-ss) to 5 seconds into a stream. However, a clip was given that had only one segment that lasted 4.33 seconds, so seeking to 5 yielded this message. I do see that you are not seeking to a position, but the output does say 'Duration: N/A'. Are you certain there is content? I've used ffmpeg very little, but could it be something with the -thresh option?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-v warning` option so you get more output from ffmpeg.  (The default is `-v info`.  Use `ffmpeg -v help` to see the different log levels available.)

---

(edit: this was written before the update, when we didn't have ffmpeg output showing that `http://localhost:8090/fac.ffm` and so on did actually make it to the ffmpeg command line.  So maybe the input to ffmpeg is empty.  Hexdump it with `hexdump -C`)

---

Looks like your problem here is that **you left out the `\` line-continuation at the end of the later lines**, so those are separate shell commands instead of args to `ffmpeg`.  You should have gotten error messages like `-f: command not found`.

---

If you're using bash (instead of `sh`), you could use a bash array variable to let you use newlines as whitespace in the argument list.

```
ffmpeg_args = (
  -v warning
  -f rawvideo
  -pixel_format bgr24
  -video_size 544x320
  -i -
  http://localhost:8090/fac.ffm
)

blah blah | ffmpeg "${ffmpeg_args[@]}"
```

Comment: peter-cordes after your suggestion  i remove -v warning i got this -see above i edit the what ouput have come.

Comment: @Ankitgupta: Are you sure your other command is actually producing video?  What if you make ffmpeg's output a regular file instead of a URL?  Or hexdump instead of piping into ffmpeg at all?

Comment: i am know little about ffmpeg ,i am not sure but there is no output video are showing , if you can elaborate me in simple way .

Comment: @Ankitgupta: `ffmpeg`'s logging output says it processed 0 frames of input.  Probably your other command only produced headers but no video frames.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes : so what can i do next  any suggestions ?